# Dial one show another phone number in Android Phone application

Tags: android

searched for a solution but haven't found anything even similar.

When dialing a number from the Android Phone application, based on a prefix predefined earlier, I intercept a call. Afterwards I place another call which number is some access number + 2 sec pause + the number intercepted + #-sign.
My question is - is there any possibility (any ACTION_CALL intent extra or something) that this intercepted and not the access number is shown in the Android Phone application?

Example:
Access Number: 999999
Prefix: 011
Number: 011552657659

Thus, newly placed call is 999999,011552657659#. 
Result: the Phone application shows 999999 and other digits are dialed tonally, while I want a user to see something 011552657659 instead.

My code is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:999999,011552657659#");
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Thank you in advance!